# Why do some conference rooms show with user icons

Tags: outlook, office365, exchange-server

In my outlook calendar, I have a few conference rooms showing an icon as a user and not a room icon

Any idea why? I am on O365.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJxNl.png

Comment: How is this question [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: Might be better on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Superuser](https://superuser.com/). Would vote to migrate that question here.